# Carousel with different heights responsive height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I've had this issue a couple of times and just left it in the past but would like to know the solution for future.

Please excuse the horrible carousel I just wrote it quickly:

http://jsfiddle.net/00wwkjux/111/

In this example div id = "7" has alot of breaks in it so that makes the entire height of the container respond to it.

```
<div class="reviewcaro">  
<div id="7">aa
aa<br><br><br><br>
aa<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>    
</div>
```

I know the reason is because even though the divs aren't visible they are all there in the overflow.

And the text at the bottom "text pushed down so far :-(" gets a big space due to it, but what is the way of making the heights responsive? So that the text bounces about staying below the divs, not just staying static to fit in with one div? Is there a way?

Hope I explained it well, not sure of exact names!

Thanks!

Comment: You can add/remove the content each time the button is clicked. Or maybe `display: none` or `height: 0` on the out of view divs. Depending on your page layout you will want to add a fixed height to a parent wrapper or the page bounces up and down and can feel a little annoying, especially if it's an autoscroller and the surfer is reading something down the page.

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen Thanks alot! Could you show me on the jsfiddle how I would do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's all I have time for at the moment..

**fiddles**

[latest fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/y7vgb2ua/) - latest code on latest fiddle

[original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/00wwkjux/117/)

Basically it's just adding an .active marker to the div in view. And of course do the opposite for your 'sub' button.

You will want to code it to know when it reaches the end (run an .each loop on page load to count the number of divs in the slider and save the number as a variable) -- i see you've already got a counter set up. Ther each loop is only neccesary if your amount of divs will change, if youre using the script on different sites or your amount of content changes day to day.

```js
var subButton = "#subButton";
var addButton = "#addButton";
var caro ="#caro";

var clicks = 0;

if (screen.width > 1){
$(addButton).click(function(){
 $('.active').addClass('remove');
 $('.active').next().addClass('active');
   $(caro).animate({
    marginLeft: '-=100%'
   }, 400, function() {
    $('.active.remove').removeClass('active remove');
    $('.active.remove').removeClass('active remove');
   });     
  clicks+=1;
  
  if (clicks > 4) 
  {
   $(caro).animate({'margin-left' :'0px'}, {duration: 400}); 
  clicks = 0;
  };   
});

$(subButton).click(function(){
 $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(caro).animate({'margin-left' : '0px'}, {duration: 400});  
 clicks = 0;
});
}
```

```css
.wrapperreview{width:100%;margin:0 auto;}
.containerreview{width:100%;position:relative;overflow:hidden;}
.reviews-carousel{
  display: flex;
  width:500%;
}
.reviewcaro {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width:20%;
  height: 0;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0 30px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.reviewcaro.active {
  height: auto;
}
.reviewcaro div {
  displaY: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
#a { height: 50px; }
#b { height: 150px; }
#c { height: 100px; }
#d { height: 250px; }
#e { height: 200px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="subButton">  sub </button>
<button id="addButton">  add </button>
<div class="wrapperreview" >
  <div class="containerreview" >
    <div class="reviews-carousel" id="caro"> 
      <div class="reviewcaro active"><div id="a">A</div></div>
      <div class="reviewcaro"><div id="b">B</div></div>
      <div class="reviewcaro"><div id="c">C</div></div>
      <div class="reviewcaro"><div id="d">D</div></div>
      <div class="reviewcaro"><div id="e">E</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
 text pushed down so far :-(
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your time doing this, I will have a try now that you have got me a lot further on and see if I can try to get it to work!

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it helps. You may want to leave it marked as unanswered for now, in case someone who has more time at the moment can provide you with a complete answer before I have more time myself.

Comment: it's strange because `$('.active').next().addClass('active');` works great going through and adding responsive height (just not resetting back down which is strange because in the CSS it tells it to go back to initial), the `$('.active').addClass('remove');
  $('.active.remove').removeClass('active remove');` seem to make it all collapse ontop of eachother.

Comment: @Beth 
 
I changed your css around a little and used display: flex here and there. Here's the latest fiddle, you may get some more ideas from it. jsfiddle.net/Hastig/00wwkjux/124

Comment: @Hatig Zusammenstellen Thanks alot that's working for the first 5 now going right! When clicks are over 4 to reset it how would I go about doing that, at the moment it seems to collapse all I think cause it doesn't know active should be id=1 again. I tried this which doesn't work `if (clicks > 4) 
  {
  $('#1 .active').next().addClass('active');
   $(caro).animate({'margin-left' :'0px'}, {duration: 400}); 
  clicks = 0;
  }; `

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to my question to make a carousel container parent containing div's of different heights that the carousel will keep changing it's height to the height of the div within, just in case anyone in the future needs it. Great for review carousel for example.

***SOLUTION***

https://jsfiddle.net/fj1y0opj/

**HTML**

```
<button id="subButton">  sub </button>
<button id="addButton">  add </button>
<div class="wrapperreview" >
  <div class="containerreview" >
    <div class="reviews-carousel" id="caro"> 
      <div class="reviewcaro active"><div id="a">A</div></div>
      <div class="reviewcaro"><div id="b">758475 84758475847584 7584758475 84758 475847584<br><br></div></div>
      <div class="reviewcaro"><div id="c">C</div></div>
      <div class="reviewcaro"><div id="d">D<br><br><br></div></div>
      <div class="reviewcaro"><div id="e">E</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapperreview{width:100%;margin:0 auto;}
.containerreview{width:100%;position:relative;overflow:hidden;}
.reviews-carousel{
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
}
.active {
  display: flex !important;
}
.reviewcaro {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0 30px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.reviewcaro.active {
  height: initial;
}
.reviewcaro div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var subButton = "#subButton";
var addButton = "#addButton";
var caro ="#caro";
var total = $(".reviewcaro").length;
var clicks = 0;

if (screen.width > 1){
$(addButton).click(function(){
    clicks++;

  if(clicks == total) {
     $(caro).animate({
     marginLeft: '-100%'
   }, 400, function() {
    $(caro).css('margin-left','0px');
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.reviewcaro:first').addClass('active');
   });       
    clicks = 0;
  } else {

   console.log(clicks);
     $(caro).animate({
     marginLeft: '-100%'
   }, 400, function() {
        $('.active').addClass('remove');
        $('.active').next().addClass('active');
      $(caro).css('margin-left','0px');
     $('.active.remove').removeClass('active remove');
   });       

  }





});

$(subButton).click(function(){
     $(caro).animate({
     marginLeft: '-100%'
   }, 400, function() {
    $(caro).css('margin-left','0px');
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.reviewcaro:first').addClass('active');
   });       
    clicks = 0;
});
}
```

@Hastig Zusammenstellen Credit to you. Thanks so much for your help getting me on the right path!

Comment: Looks good! Here's a newer version of the one I was working on. I simplified the html a bit and added the 'if last item reached' code. If I keep working on it I'll make it so one can keep scrolling in one direction and have it wrap seamlessly (without shuffling back to the first/last item in carousel) https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/y7vgb2ua/

Answer (score 0):

The container div will always stretch to the size of the largest child. I believe the only way you can get around this is to recalculate the height each time the carousel advances. So, when the active div changes, check the height of it and set it in the javascript.

You could also download a copy of Slick Carousel by Ken Wheeler. He's achieved the effect you're looking for: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/. Check out his code and see if you can replicate it in your own.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How would I recalculate the height each time the carousel is clicked to check the height of it? Not the best at javascript as you can probably tell from the jsfiddle!

Comment: Looks Like @HastigZusammenstellen has you on the right track.